# How to reset protobuf-net RuntimeTypeModel.Default model?

Tags: protobuf-net

I try to unit test protobuf-net configurations, unfortunately as it turns out there is no `Clear` method (or similar) on `RuntimeTypeModel.Default`.
Since I used  `RuntimeTypeModel.Default` throughout the app, I don't want to switch to `RuntimeTypeModel.Create()`.

Is there a way to reset/clear/delete types added to `RuntimeTypeModel.Default` by `Add` method?

Comment: Did you manage to figure out a way to do this? I'm also finding that once you register Types as surrogates, you can't re-add them; for instance in the case of Unit Test classes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with xUnit tests. The constructor would instantiate for each of the test and the RuntimeTypeModel would already have the surrogate type in there and fail. The solution is to use ClassFixture in xUnit ( I believe it's TestFixture for nUnit?)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using NodaTime;
using ProtoBuf.Meta;
using Quantum.Serialisation;
using Quantum.Serialisation.Surrogates;
using Xunit;

namespace Quantum.SerialisationTests
{

    public class TestFixture : IDisposable
    {
        private RuntimeTypeModel model;

        public TestFixture()
        {
            RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
            model = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
            model.Add(typeof (ZonedDateTimeSurrogate), true);
            model.Add(typeof (ZonedDateTime), false).SetSurrogate(typeof (ZonedDateTimeSurrogate));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }

    public class ProtobufTests : IClassFixture<TestFixture>
    {

        public ProtobufTests()
        {
        }

        // Tests go here

        public void SetFixture(TestFixture data)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

No matter how many tests you have in the ProtobufTests spec the surrogate is only ever added once.